# Integer Literals in WebAssembly Binary

Tags: webassembly

I am using [this demo](https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wat2wasm/) to understand how WebAssembly text format is compiled into binary.

One thing I don't understand is the integer literals used in `i32.const` and `i64.const`.

For instance, the code for `i32.const -1` is as follows:

```
0000024: 41                                        ; i32.const
0000025: 7f                                        ; i32 literal
```

How exactly does `0x7f` (127 in decimal) relate to -1?

Here is the code for `i32.const 1234`:

```
0000024: 41                                        ; i32.const
0000025: d209                                      ; i32 literal
```

I know that WASM is little-endian, so the first byte in the WASM hexadecimal representation (`d2`) corresponds to the last byte in normal binary notation. The binary representation of 1234 in 32 bits is `00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010`. The last byte is 210, which is `d2` in hexadecimal. That matches what I see in the WASM code. But the byte before that is 4. Where does `09` come from in the WASM code?

There are many other examples that don't make sense to me. Where are these integer literals coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x7f is the **two's complement representation** of -1.

0x31 is the **opcode** for **i32.const**.

d209 (0x09d2) is the **Unsigned LEB128** of 1234 (0x04d2)

[Unsigned LEB128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128#Unsigned_LEB128)

Comment: ULEB128 is the answer! `0x7f` isn't the two's complement of 1 by itself, but it's the ULEB128 encoding of the two's complement of 1. Wikipedia's page on ULEB128 includes working JavaScript code for those who are interested in trying it out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128#JavaScript_code.

Comment: @grandinero -1 is a signed value. That means using Signed LEB128. For one byte signed numbers, the result is the same as two's complement.